# how can i determine the working directory a fatjar was invoked from

Tags: fatjar, working-directory

I have a project which i have made into a fatjar. Gradle pus this into the /build/libs

I have gone to this directory and invoked the fatjar with a file as a param.

steps

1. cd /build/libs
2. java -jar .jar --execute script.groovy

this launches the Main-Class - a launcher class that reads the args from command line.

however what you get as the file name is 'script.groovy'  and thats intended to be from the same directory as i have the jar file

Inside the class /fatjar however if you look at

```
System.getProperty("user.dir")
```

or

```
Path path = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(".").toAbsolutePath()
```

they all report the path as the projectRoot directory - and not where the jar itself was run from (/build/libs)

inside your class, inside the fatjar, how do you determine the directory where the fatjar actually is when invoked from the command line?

Answer (score 0):

I struggled a bit on this as well. You can find some hints in StartupInfoLogger.java from spring. I am using 2.1.5 spring boot version.

Here is some sample code.

```
public class MyTestFatJarMainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyTestFatJarMainClass.class, args);
        // The needed code start below 

        // The class is MyTestFatJarMainClass.class, but it can be any class in your app
        ApplicationHome home = new ApplicationHome(MyTestFatJarMainClass.class);
        String path = (home.getSource() != null) ? home.getSource().getAbsolutePath() : "";
        // Now you got the path, it contains the jar file itself.
        System.out.println("DINDA " + s + " path " + path);

    }
}
```

You could also read String property = System.getProperty("user.dir");

Check which one of them can be useful for you.